# Cannot get rid of empty Interesting Tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching, ignored-tags

I added and removed some tags today on my meta account while testing something (I previously had no tags marked as interesting). Now, however, under interesting tags I see a blank box (same color as an interesting tag would be), followed by the 'x' button to remove it. The tool tip for the "tag" says "see all questions tagged ''". I click the 'x' to remove the tag (or remove it from my preferences), but as soon as I load a page displaying the interesting tags, the blank one is back again. I have tried this and observed the same behavior on SU and SO. Additionally, on SO and meta I have the same problem with Ignored Tags. I did not try this with Ignored Tags on SU, but I have never had an ignored tag on SU, and do not see the blank box. On SF, I have never had an Interesting or Ignored tag and do not see the empty boxes. I have seen the behavior described above using both Chrome 2.0.172.39 and 2.0.172.43 and IE 8.0.6001.18702.

[alt text http://img196.yfrog.com/img196/3840/interestingbug.jpg](http://img196.yfrog.com/img196/3840/interestingbug.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed your preferences in the database, so your account should be good.

We've recently done some refactorings around tags and the insertion of empty tags into preferences might be a new bug - thanks for reporting it!

Comment: I have the same problem on Meta, with Opera, Safari and Firefox.

Comment: I have the same problem on Meta too.

Comment: I have the same problem on SuperUser too!

Comment: I had this *feature* for months on SO... never thought it was a bug.  I interested in nothing...  If it helps I was able to get rid of the empty tag after I added another tag, then deleting the empty tag seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Able to reproduce in Opera via the following steps:

- Enter tag to interesting/ignore list
- Tap double space after the word
- Click <kbd>Add</kbd> to save to list
- Should now see the empty tag **`[ ]`** on the list of watched next time you refresh

Maybe those were the steps. Who knows. The blank little **`[ ]`** up on the interesting list says something.

Comment: Really? It doesn't come back up later as a ghost?

Answer (score 0):

Using FireFox + FireBug, add a new tag to the list (the one with the empty tag present). Look at what is posted to the server via XHR to see what tag it is, or whether it is really a tag at all. From there it should be possible to do some more analysis on the issue.