# Removing an ignored tag doesn't work

Tags: bug, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot get rid of empty Interesting Tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17541/cannot-get-rid-of-empty-interesting-tag)

I recently removed one of my ignored tags. When I refresh the page, I get an empty tag in the 'Ignored Tags' list that I can't remove.

Comment: @Andy: No problem, I hope that in the future you will stop duplicating the data in the tags in the title. That is redundant and just adds noise to the questions page.

Comment: @Rich: I hide questions with 'bug' tags, so I forgot that would be an issue :)

Comment: Another demonstration why ignoring content is a bad thing for the site.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me on IE7.